# Which flexible wires can be shaped by hands?

Tags: wire, toys

I'm planning to make a toy for my kid using flexible colorful wires. Wires which are coated and can be bend in any shape with hand. So different shapes can be made.

Suggest me type of some wires or their properties which are flexible but can hold a shape. So that I can search for them online or on some store.

Comment: This seems like a pretty toy, but it may not be safe for your baby.  The sharp ends of the wires may poke your baby. Also, if your baby chews on the the colorful insulation, pieces may come off and present a choking hazard or may be poisonous.

Comment: @BrettFromLA Thanks a lot to highlight security points. I shouldn't have mentioned "baby". My kid is 4 years old now. So she takes care. I'll shield both ends.

Comment: That does make a difference! Then I agree with the pipe cleaner answer from James.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a web search for "pipe cleaner craft".  These wires have a fuzzy coating and are intended for crafting.

They can be found very cheap for hundreds of foot-long wires of various colors.  For example, on Amazon.com I see 600 pieces for about $15 US.

[image]

Comment: I also found telephone wire useful but only 2 colors are available. What type of wire used in [earphone cord organizer](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1oxdlQpXXXXbbXpXXq6xXFXXXM/10sets-Lovely-Gifts-Minions-cartoon-style-Earphone-Cable-Wire-Cord-Organizer-Holder-Winder-For-Headphone-Wire.jpg_640x640.jpg). It is really flexible and can hold the shape. I was wondering if such wires are available in Polymer coating...